# Haskell preprocessor - pound sign with curly braces

Tags: haskell, preprocessor

Browsing sources of Haskell SDL bindings, I've stumbled upon the following piece:

```
#include "SDL/SDl.h"

fromAudioFormat AudioS8 = #{const AUDIO_S8}
```

What does `#{const AUDIO_S8}` part actually do? At a glance, it extracts a symbol from `SDL.h`, but I'd like to know exactly what it does and how to construct similar things. I'm particularly curious about `const` modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [`hsc2hs`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/utils.html#writing-haskell-interfaces-to-c-code-hsc2hs) syntax. The `const` directive says "output the literal numeric value of this C expression into the generated `.hs` file". `#` just invokes the preprocessor. The curly braces are optional - `hsc2hs` just reads to the end of the line if you omit the braces, so you could just as easily write

```
fromAudioFormat AudioS8 = #const AUDIO_S8
```

For more on the specific preprocessor directives see [the docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/utils.html#input-syntax).